# Can macOS add a torn edge to images in clipboard?

Tags: macos, automator, image-editing

I'd like to be able to add torn edges to images in the clipboard on my Mac.  I do a lot of documentation and having the ability to add a torn edge around a screen shot helps the people that try to click the button in the screenshots understand that its an image of the button, not the button itself...

I used Greenshot on Windows but now I've moved to Mac I've found that greenshot on Mac just lacks too many features so I'm now using Shottr which has all the features I need except torn edge.

'Torn edge' adds a border to the image to make it look like its been torn from a larger sheet of paper.  In greenshot it looks like the image on this page:
https://getgreenshot.org/2014/12/22/a-little-present-from-us-greenshot-1-2/

or this image

https://getgreenshot.org/assets/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/incrementing-labels-300x185.png

In Pages it looks like this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4741142?sortBy=best

I have looked at using imagemagick or Pages along with automator to automatically create a copy of the image in a subfolder of 'screenshots' that has the effect applied but being new to scripting on this mac I'm not even sure what words to put into google to search.

Any pointers on where to start would be appreciated.  If there is a javascript solution that might also work as I also use CopyQ which can process the clipboard contents using ECMAScript

Is this something that can be automated?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. There are many automation wizards here, but they might not understand what the effect you see as "torn edges" is without an example linked or edited into the question. Pages is fully scriptable, so perhaps editing that out will let people focus on your issue and not some misconceptions. Excellent work documenting your search otherwise!